# How do I encrypt web.config connection strings during deployment from the command line, specifying the encryption provider?

Tags: encryption, msbuild, msdeploy, pubxml

I know I can do this to encrypt connection strings in a web site that is already deployed:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe connectionStrings
```

I can also encrypt connection strings in a web site before it is deployed by doing this:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings .\WebApplication1
```

I also know how to make my own RSA key, install it on several computers, and set up an encryption provider for that key, so I can encrypt it on one machine and publish it on another:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings .\WebApplication1 -prov MyProvider
```

I can even tell MSBuild to encrypt the connection strings for me during deployment by adding a line to the .pubxml file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#encrypt_webconfig).

But what I really need to do is this:

1. create the web site source code and save it in source control with the connection strings decrypted;
2. build the web site, transforming the web.config file with web.debug.config or web.release.config;
3. encrypt the connection strings in the transformed web.config *using my custom encryption provider;*
4. and then publish it

all from an automated process.  Note: I can't encrypt the connection strings first and then build the web site, because I have to transform the web.config file before encrypting it.  I don't want to publish the web site first and then encrypt the connection strings, because I don't want the decrypted connection strings to be on the web server even for a brief time.  I want to encrypt the connection strings during the deploy process, but with my own encryption provider.  How can I do that?  It's got to be possible.  Any combination of msbuild commands, msdeploy commands, and .pubxml file settings would be acceptable.

I've tried searching for how to do this -- I really have -- but I can't find a comprehensive reference for msbuild.exe / msdeploy.exe / *.pubxml ANYWHERE.  (That's a separate question.)